# ASP.NET 4 application redirecting to ASP.NET Core login page question

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor-server-side

I am trying to get an ASP.NET 4 app to redirect to a login page on an ASP.NET Core (Blazor) app but can't work out what the default landing page is for the ASP.NET Core app.

I have an ASP.NET 4 (.NET 4.7) web application that has an ASP.NET Core (Blazor) app nested underneath as an IIS application using the same IIS app pool.

```
AppPool:  AppX
URL1:     /parentApp
URL2:     /parentApp/childApp
```

The parent web app is set to use forms authentication and I am trying to redirect to the login page on the child app (or even just redirect to the child app which should then load the correct login page).

My question is how do I get the URL of the login page (its a default Blazor server app) so that I can add it to the forms tag in the `web.config` of the parentApp?

Regards

Comment: Whether you are using Asp.net Core Identity and Scaffold Identity in the Blazor server page application? If you are using Asp.net core Identity, the login page should in the `Areas\Identity\Pages\Account` folder, the local login url as blow: `https://localhost:44347/Identity/Account/Login`, in your scenario, the url like this: `/parentApp/childApp/Identity/Account/Login`. If you are not using Asp.net Core Identity, it is better to share the relates folder structure in the blazor application.

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a go.  The scenario is legacy app (.net framework) sharing the cookie with modern app which performs the forms auth.  The modern app will either be .net 5 blazor or mvc4 depending on which one I can get working.

Comment: Also, what is the 'relates' folder structure?

Comment: Hi @AndyW, About the folder structure, generally in the asp.net 5 blazor application the web pages located in the Pages folder, but I'm not sure if you change the web page's location or not, and whether you are using areas or not, so, if you are not use Asp.net core Identity to login, it is better to share the folder structure, then we can according to to set the request url.

Comment: I thanks, the blazor app uses asp.net core identity, but the .net framework app does not (asp.net 3.5).,